# R Shiny - Build a tabsetPanel from a list from selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to develop this tabsetpanel for a while but without success. The goal is to assemble the tabs dynamically. After the user click the search button, the tabs will be assembled from the user's selection in selectizeInput. Each tab will have a specific content. When the user presses the search button again, the tabs must be built again with the information from selectizeInput without duplication.

I appreciate any help.

[the result should be like this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53VY7.png)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Examples of DataTables",
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            selectizeInput(
                'state', 'State', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE
            ),
            actionButton("search", "Search"),

        ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                id = 'dataset',
                tabPanel("tab1", verbatimTextOutput("tab1"))
            )

        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$tab1 <- renderPrint({
        "tab1"
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to show what you've tried so far. Have you looked at tutorials on how to generate UI on `server` side?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figure it out using insertUI and removeUI. To loop the tabsetPanel I used do.call method and *voila*!!!